# Convert dd-M-yyyy to mySQL datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL varchar column full with dates stored in dd-M-yyyy format. E.g:

```
Row 1: 12-jan-2010
Row 2: 23-jun-2016
```

What's the best way to convert this to mySQL datetime format using php?

Comment: The `DATE` type will suffice if you're not required to store the time of day. Just saying.

Comment: True, but I will prefer to use datetime to future proof. The column holds the value of the last modified date to the product and I can see the use of more accurate date/time reporting down the track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be done without using php:

```
update myTable set newcol = STR_TO_DATE(oldcol, '%d-%M-%Y')
```

Comment: +1 No need to go through the trouble to `SELECT`, convert in PHP then `UPDATE` for every row.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your timezone is UTC: see `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Use `strtotime()` to convert the existing string to a UNIX timestamp.

Use `date()` to convert it back to one or another standard format, e.g. `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Put it back into MySQL.